# Click two buttons in the same and open the action of the second button using qml and Qt6

Tags: qt, button, qml, click, qtquick2

I have these 2 buttons and I want to click on both to open the onClick action of the second button. How can I do that to get my desired result? Maybe to use signals?

```
Button {
    id: btnLevel1
    x: 1016
    y: 492
    width: 554
    height: 67
    onClicked: classA.newGameWindow()
    text: "May God\nHave Mercy"
    background: Rectangle {
        color: "transparent"
    }

    font.family: "Inria Serif"
    font.pixelSize: 20
}

Text {
    id: very_hard_level
    color: "white"
    horizontalAlignment: Text.AlignHCenter
    verticalAlignment: Text.AlignTop
    wrapMode: Text.Wrap
    font.weight: Font.Normal
}

Button {
    id: btn2
    x: 58
    y: 246
    width: 188
    height: 34
    onClicked: classA.newGameWindow()
    text: qsTr("New Game")
    background: Rectangle {
        color: "transparent"
    }

    font.family: "Inria Serif"
    font.pixelSize: 26

    Text {
        id: new_Game
        color: "white"
        horizontalAlignment: Text.AlignLeft
        verticalAlignment: Text.AlignTop
        wrapMode: Text.Wrap
        font.weight: Font.Normal
    }
}
```

I tried to use MouseArea but didn't work and I don't know what to do

Comment: Can you better explain what you want? As far as I can see the two buttons call the same function `classA.newGameWindow()` which as far as I understand is what you want?

Comment: If you mean that you want to trigger the same block of code for both buttons, you can extract your logic to a seperate function.

Comment: @iam_peter I want to make both buttons to be clicked one after another and the last one to have the action to open a new window

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I still don't fully understand your use case hence the solution could be wrong.

I've used a button group to keep track of the buttons in use and also to unify the `onClicked` signal call. One pitfall here could be to add a `AbstractButton` that doesn't have the custom property `activated` which can be checked for.

When a button is pressed the `activated` property of that button is set to `true`, if not all buttons of the group are `activated` the function exits, if all buttons are `activated` the background of the root `Window` is set to yellow, which would be your entry point to call a function as far as I understood your example. Also the custom button `MyButton` includes an indicator `Rectangle` to show the `activated` state of that button.

That said depending on your use case there could potentially be better solutions to your problem.

```
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Controls

Window {
    id: root
    width: 640
    height: 480
    visible: true
    title: qsTr("Hello World")

    ButtonGroup {
        id: buttonGroup
        onClicked: function(button) {
            button.activated = true

            for (let i = 0; i < buttonGroup.buttons.length; ++i) {
                if (!buttonGroup.buttons[i].activated)
                    return
            }

            console.log("All buttons pressed")
            root.color = "yellow"
        }
    }

    component MyButton: Row {
        property alias text: button.text

        spacing: 10

        Button {
            id: button
            property bool activated: false
            ButtonGroup.group: buttonGroup
        }

        Rectangle {
            width: 20
            height: 20
            color: button.activated ? "green" : "red"
            anchors.verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter
        }
    }

    Column {
        spacing: 10
        anchors.centerIn: parent

        MyButton { text: "Button #1" }
        MyButton { text: "Button #2" }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Jürgen Lutz. You should use functions.

Because a transition is involved, your real issue could be that of timing, of which, either a well-placed Qt.callLater() is needed or something similar, e.g.

```
Button {
    onClicked: {
        function1();
        function2();
        Qt.callLater( () => { classA.newGameWindow(); } );
    }
}
```

Another solution you may wish to consider is by using `SequentialAnimation` with `ScriptAction` to pace out your functions and page transition. You can even add `PauseAnimation` and `PropertyAnimation`:

```
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Controls
import QtQuick.Layouts
Page {
    background: Rectangle { color: "#848895" }
    title: "ScriptAction Demo"
    Button {
        id: btn
        text: "abc"
        onClicked: SequentialAnimation {
            PropertyAnimation {
                target: btn // newGameWindow
                property: "opacity"
                from: 1
                to: 0.5
                duration: 500
            }
            ScriptAction { script: function1() }
            ScriptAction { script: function2() }
            PauseAnimation { duration: 100 }
            ScriptAction { script: classA.newGameWindow() }
            PropertyAnimation {
                target: btn // newGameWindow
                property: "opacity"
                from: 0.5
                to: 1
                duration: 500
            }
        }
    }
    function function1() {
        btn.text = "abc " + (new Date());
    }
    function function2() {
        btn.palette.buttonText = Qt.rgba(Math.random()/2, Math.random()/2, Math.random()/2, 1);
    }
}
```

You can try the [latter example online!](https://stephenquan.github.io/qmlonline/?zcode=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)

Comment: I couldn't run the second code snippet. Is the code correct? (*using Qt 6.6.1*)

Comment: @smr I corrected the syntax error and provided a runnable link.